# Excel INDEX and MATCH formulas - find column letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is it possible to replace part in bold ('FPS raw'!M:M & 'FPS raw'!K:K) so that it finds the right column letters each time, based on E2 formula: B2 ->> =INDEX(**'FPS raw'!M:M**,MATCH(A2,**'FPS raw'!K:K**,0)+1)

B2 formula:

```
=INDEX('FPS raw'!M:M,MATCH(A2,'FPS raw'!K:K,0)+1)
```

E2 formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(A1,'FPS raw'!1:1,0),4),"1","")
```

[image]

Formulas used:

[image]

Comment: "Part in bold?" This question is not clear to me. May be just me.

Comment: I meant: 'FPS raw'!M:M & 'FPS raw'!K:K

Comment: Maybe just `=INDEX('FPS raw'!A:Z,MATCH(A2,'FPS raw'!K:K,0)+1,MATCH(A1,'FPS raw'!1:1,0))` ?

Comment: Or, B2 copied down: =INDEX(OFFSET('FPS raw'!A$1,0,MATCH(B$1,'FPS raw'!$1:$1,0)-1,100),MATCH(A2,OFFSET('FPS raw'!A$1,0,MATCH(A$1,'FPS raw'!$1:$1,0)-1,100),0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX('FPS raw'!$A:$ZZ,0,MATCH($B$1,'FPS raw'!$1:$1,0)),MATCH($A2,INDEX('FPS raw'!$A:$ZZ,0,MATCH($A$1,'FPS raw'!$1:$1,0)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: It returns 0 value for all IDs, which is not true.

Comment: it is hard to trouble shoot without test data.

Comment: I have edited my post with a picture, the references are different but the formula is the same.  You can see that it works for me.